# Determine the image orientation of image in Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

I need to determine the image orientation of the image to be displayed in an imageView. My app stores images in Firebase Storage and uses the SDWebImage integration in Firebase like so:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageRef)
```

Thought that the metadata would hold enough information to determine image orientation, so I tried this:

```
imageRef.getMetadata(completion: (StorageMetadata?, Error?) -> Void)
```

While I'm able to retrieve the metadata, I can't seem to figure out the orientation from it. Accordning to the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties) image height or width cannot be obtained from metadata.

I know I could store image orientation info in my realtime database upon uploading the image, but I'd rather not go that way.

Earlier I used this

```
imageRef.getData(maxSize: Int64, completion: (Data?, Error?) -> Void)
```

which can give you an UIImage to play around with. While I can get the image orientation this way, it's too slow for my (client's) taste.

**Is it possible to determine image orientation from Firebase Storage info only?**

Comment: Have some RND over EXIF interface and how to use it in IOS

Comment: What does that even mean? :-)

Comment: Exif interface is used to determine the correct  orientation of images. its algorith general and can be used in any language.

Comment: But I clearly stated I wanted to use Firebase. If not possible I have another solution, also stated in my question

Comment: it was slow since you were downloading data and then processing it... 
i am afraid you have to do it manually like you suggested by saving orientation manually by the time of upload... or may be someone have better solution here

Comment: Yes, that’s my question exactly